# Prove that the number of full nodes plus one is qual to the number of leaves in a nonempty binary tree

Tags: proof-techniques, trees, binary-trees, induction

I'm trying to write an induction statement to prove a full node in a tree but I have no idea how to do that. I've always been terrible when it comes to logic. Where do I even start with this?

I know that a full node has 2 children.

Comment: Consider an arbitrary binary tree with `n` nodes. Where could you attach a `n+1`-th node? What would be the effect on the node counts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, an induction proof consists of a base case and an induction step. For trees that is usually *structural induction*, based on inductive ways trees are built.

The *base case* considers the smallest binary tree, which cannot be composed further. Show that one has the Property.

The *induction step* argues that the Property is true for any tree $T$ assuming the Property holds for its subtrees $T_{\textrm{left}}$ and $T_{\textrm{right}}$. That assumption is called the *induction hypothesis*.

There is another approach, induction based on the number of (full) nodes, called *natural induction*. Base case has a single full node. Induction step argues Property is true assuming Property holds for any tree having less full nodes.